# SSRS using XML data and XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, charts, ssrs-2008

I am doing research for a project that currently has xslt reports, and we are considering moving the reports to SSRS.

However, the stored procedures return XML data and I would like to know if anyone has had experience using XML & XPath and SSRS to display reports / graphics / charts etc.

Any advice / resources are appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe we've done this at my current workplace but I'll ask a colleague tomorrow (it's 6pm here) and if he's unsure I'll run up a test to see if it's possible. If you don't see an answer from me 48 hours from now feel free to prompt me :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, SSRS likes to work with datasets. But it can query a XML data source and make it a dataset.

What I have done before, is querying a web service from SSRS and displaying the result. For example the report server web service (http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx). Querying the listChildren method for example would look something like:

```
    <Query>
   <Method Name="ListChildren" 
Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices">
   <Parameters>
       <Parameter Name="Item">
           <DefaultValue>/Reports</DefaultValue>
       </Parameter>
     <Parameter Name="Recursive">
           <DefaultValue>true</DefaultValue>
       </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Using a datasource of type XML.

But in your case, you have a stored procedure that returns xml data... One way would be to publish the stored procedure as a web service and make this kind of call.

Or, make a new stored procedure that wraps the xml-stored procedure and converts the xml data to a regular dataset on the fly.